# SQL Error: ORA-14006: invalid partition name when moving partition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl, database-partitioning

I want to move the partition to another tablespace but when I run the following script I get the error ORA-14006.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MOVE PARTITION 'SYS_P001' TABLESPACE 'DATA07' COMPRESS;
```

Comment: Identifiers (names) need to be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes in SQL.

Comment: Can a name be given without quotation marks ?

Comment: Yes that as well, but the single quotes are only for string constants, never for identifiers